# How can I bulk edit Conditional Formatting rules in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

My Google Sheet Conditional Formatting rules are full of `Strings`, like `=INDIRECT("Settings!D18")`.

If I rearrange things on my `Settings` sheet and `D18` becomes `X45`, is there a way for me to do a global Search/ Replace to reflect that?

Comment: You could do this with [Google Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script) -  see [ConditionalFormatRuleBuilder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/conditional-format-rule-builder).

Comment: @ziganotschka please `answer` the question and I will Accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### You could do this with [Google Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script) to bulk edit the conditional formatting rules programmatically

For this, use the [ConditionalFormatRuleBuilder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/conditional-format-rule-builder) and the [withCriteria()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/conditional-format-rule-builder#withcriteriacriteria,-args) builder.

Sample:

```js
function bulkUpdateConditionalFormatting(){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var rules = sheet.getConditionalFormatRules();
  var newRules = [];
  var newCriteriaValues
  rules.forEach(function(rule){
    var booleanCondition = rule.getBooleanCondition();
    Logger.log(booleanCondition.getCriteriaValues());
    if (booleanCondition != null && booleanCondition.getCriteriaType() == 'CUSTOM_FORMULA') {
      var values = booleanCondition.getCriteriaValues()
      values.forEach(function(value,i){values[i] = value.replace("D18", "D45")});
      var newRule = SpreadsheetApp.newConditionalFormatRule()
      .withCriteria(booleanCondition.getCriteriaType(), values)
      .setBackground(booleanCondition.getBackground())
      .setRanges(rule.getRanges())
      .build();
      newRules.push(newRule);
    }
  })
  sheet.setConditionalFormatRules(newRules);
}
```